# Why is rails-erb-loader failing with exit code 127?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to work on a project my friend built. It is ruby on rails, and he is on an m1 mac. I however, am on windows (running the project via docker), and am completely new to Ruby. When I run the project, after bundle installing and yarn installing, I get this error in the debug console and have no idea why. Any ideas?

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js):
Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 127
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/flightdeck/node_modules/rails-erb-loader/index.js:128:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:301:12)
    at ./app/javascript/packs/stripe_checkout.js.erb (http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:2983:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:20:30)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:1426:76)
    at ./app/javascript/packs/application.js (http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:1734:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:84:18
    at http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-92b054144842785867e5.js:87:10
```

Comment: Looks like similar to the issue: https://github.com/usabilityhub/rails-erb-loader/issues/63, could try methods mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was due to some files having been CRLF when they should have been LF... once I changed these files manually, the project ran successfully.